# Cakephp:How to validate my select options so that it restricts duplication of options selected

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a selection drop down menu, and I want the user to select two options for a field in the database. The problem is how do I make it to disallow duplication of select options, currently it's saving all options even when they are the same.

Code in my add.ctp for the select options is:

```
echo $this->Form->select("ProgrammeChoice.programme_code.0",$finals);
echo $this->Form->select("ProgrammeChoice.programme_code.1",$finals);
```

And the variable `$finals` is bringing the select options from another table in the database, it's in the controller and the code is:

```
$finals = array_merge($filtered_programs,$non_preq_programs);
```

So please, I want help to validate my select menu to deny duplicate selections on submission.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validation rule and compare the values as described here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

In the validation method your data is stored in `$this->data`.

It should look similar to this:

```
public function compare($field1) {
    if($field1 === $this->data['ProgrammeChoice']['programm_code']['1']) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```